# When a file is copied from usb flash, why does its speed increase and decrease?

Tags: windows, usb

Why does this happens when I try to copy my files to/from a usb flash memory? What causes this fluctuation?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

File transfer speed depends both on file size and the number of files. As the size and type of file being copied changes the speed will fluctuate. You can read more here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/2ve4g6/eli5_why_do_pc_to_usb_transfer_rates_mbs/